# how to achieve high throughput server with netty4

Tags: java, netty, throughput

how to achieve high throughput server with netty4?
The package is small about 16byte~0.5K, tps about 8.8w/s in my benchmark and can not rise, are there some parameter tuning recommendations in netty4 to benifit small package?
The code is [RocketMQ](https://github.com/alibaba/RocketMQ?source=cc), It is a MQ with a self-define store structure, also use the private protocol between broker and client.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: server runtime environment: Gigabit LAN(util in 23M, out 18M), cpu with 16 cores(util 60%), jvm heap set 6G

Comment: Without knowing the code it's hard to tell but maybe you want to use ChannelOption.TCP_NO_DELAY = false and see if it helps.

Comment: i try ChannelOption.TCP_NO_DELAY=false, but it does not work well. Also i increase SO_SNDBUF and SO_RCVBUF to 16k, and still little improvement

Comment: I think without seeing your code and some profiling data it's impossible to help

Comment: the source code is [RocketMQ](https://github.com/alibaba/RocketMQ?source=cc).  It is a MQ with a self-define store structure, also use the private protocol between broker and client.

Comment: I try to use PooledByteBufAllocator instead of UnPooledByteBufAllocator in my experiment, and seems improve a lot. i want to know the difference between PooledByteBuf and UnPooledByteBuf,  how to set nHeapArena, nDirectArena, pageSize, maxOrder value, is there some guide line about tuning and document?
Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Like Norman Maurer said in his comment, without some code and profiling it is hard to help. But I'll give it a try...

Since each packet is so small, you will have a lot of overhead sending them individually, that's because of how Netty is designed. Once you send a message it goes through an entire chain (the pipeline), although helpful, it helps keeping things simple and modularised, but it quickly add up if you are sending several small sized messages.

As a solution you could try place them on a queue that gets flushed every 10 milliseconds or after 100 packets been have filled. Please note that this **WILL** cause a increase in latency, specially when there's only a few packets being sent.

Comment: yeah, this may improve thuoughput, but data reliability will be another problem, also about latency.

Comment: You can't have both, sadly. Also, are you using pooled buffers? Direct or heap?